# XSLT. Two possible output values, multiple if statements. Is there a way to do this?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have two possible values that I can output "A" and "B"

The problem that I am having is that for output "A", it has to satisfy 3-4 conditions, otherwise return "B". I tried using   but I cannot figure it out.

I tried doing something like below

```
<xsl:if>Cond1
<xsl:if>Cond2
<xsl:if>Cond3
</xsl:if>
</xsl:if>
A
</xsl:if>
B
```

But this just returns both A and B if all the conditions are satisfied. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="Cond1 and Cond2 and Cond3">A</xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>B</xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```